# Cannot setState inside Firestore add promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

At a loss here. I've tried many variations of this but basically I am trying to set the state of uploadRefId to the id returned once I create a new collection. I can see the id is generated via console.log but the setState function does not seem to work within the scope of this promise (the uploadRefId is null)?

```
const [uploadRefId, setUploadRefId] = React.useState(null);

let uploadRefCol = await firestore.collection("uploads");
await uploadRefCol.add(uploadData)
  .then( (uploadDataRef) => {
    console.log('uploadDataRef.id: ', uploadDataRef.id);
    setUploadRefId(uploadDataRef.id);
    console.log('uploadRefId', uploadRefId);
  })
  .catch( (error) => {
    console.log('Error!', error)
});
```

Comment: Can you try second console statement in outside of that and see? `  React.useEffect(() => console.log('uploadRefId', uploadRefId), [uploadRefId]);`

Answer (score 0):

Changing state can be funny throughout the life cycle of React.

If your `uploadDataRef.id` is of type string see if this helps:

```
const [uploadRefId, setUploadRefId] = React.useState('');
```

If it is a numeric value see if `setUploadRefId` works with this:

```
const [uploadRefId, setUploadRefId] = React.useState(0);
```

This may not be a solution per say but it could lead you to one.

Answer (score 0):

```
setUploadRefId(uploadDataRef.id);
```

> Above is async update state so if you immediately use state value then the value is yet not set and you are trying to access the value

```
  useEffect(() => {
 console.log('uploadRefId', uploadRefId);
})
```

> So above use effect runs on every update in the state you can watch out for any state change

[Code sandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-cookies-d71k9)

Comment: Thanks! This helped. I think it's some weird timing issue. I see the state being set but it doesn't happen in time for the second console.log for some reason.